# sas enter macro date written as yyyymmdd

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Here's how I enter and work with a date as a macro variable:

```
%let x = %SYSEVALF('01jan2012'd);
%put &x; *see the date as sas sees it;
%put %SYSFUNC(putn(&x,yymmn.)); *see the date as yyyymm;
```

This is great, but I'm tired of entering dates as `'01jan2012'd`.  In special circumstances, I might want to pass in the date as a macro variable `y`, where `y` is in the form `yyyymmdd`, something like this:

```
%let y = 20120101;
%let x = %SYSEVALF(&y);
```

Of course, this doesn't work.  So, given `y`, what should I use instead of `%let x = %SYSEVALF(&y);` to have `x` as a macro variable for the date as sas sees dates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off: if you're entering them in by hand, *use SAS conventions*.  Enter it as '01JAN2012'd.  It is more quickly readable than a YYYYMMDD value, for one, and regardless of that it is *what other SAS programmers expect*.

Second: I wouldn't use %SYSEVALF() in either case.  %let x='01JAN2012'd; is sufficient in almost every case, and odds are if it's not then you're doing something in a less efficient or standard way.  Unless you're intending to use 18993 in text somewhere (in which case, okay, you can use this) '01JAN2012'd is the right way to store this in a macro variable - let SAS convert it to 18993 later.

Finally:

```
%let y=20120101;
%let x=%sysfunc(inputn(&y,YYMMDD8.));
```

is the simplest way to do what you're asking.

Comment: Running that block of code exactly as you have it leads to "ERROR: Open code statement recursion detected."

Comment: Sounds like you missed a semicolon, then, probably after the first line.  That code runs fine on my machine.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think I missed it, but upon restarting SAS, everything works.

Comment: OSR essentially only occurs when you miss a semicolon between assigning a macro variable a value, and using it.  It requires some sort of statement like "%let x=...stuff... &x ... ";  which is most common when missing semicolons.

Comment: @zkurtz The ERROR was probably a result of something that had already been submitted in your SAS session prior to you submitting Joe's code.  This also explains why the restart fixed it.

Comment: @Joe I know we're probably going to disagree here but I changed to this approach: `%let x = %sysfunc(mdy(1,1,2014)); %let y = %eval(&x - 1); %put &=y;` Because you can then use the expression within `%eval()` statements if there's further operations you would like to do.  A good example being current date -1 (in this case swap `mdy()` to `date()`).  If I had substituted `%let x = '01jan2014'd;` in my above example I would have gotten "ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function...".

Comment: Joe, seems the `%sysevalf()` may actually be best practice when using date literals to save dates to macro variables.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722797/sas-sql-macro-incremental-date-range  .  You may want to update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
data _null_;
    Call Symput('NAME',put(today()-1,yymmdd10.));
run;
```

You simply rename your code by changing the NAME to the macro name and call it as usual by &NAME

I hope this helps - or to simply input a date in that form

```
input(put(DATE,8.), yymmdd8.) AS DATENAME format=ddMMYY10.
```